# Hoow to remove Items from the Array dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I need a function which removes some items from array dynamically.

for example:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 9, 5, 7, 6, 8, etc.];
```

I need to remove all items before item "6", but after remove it stop the function and don't remove next items before next item "6".

There are word's array in project and I need to filter it. need to remove all items before one specific word.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

findIndex and slice will do it

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 9, 5, 7, 6, 8];
const findNum = 6;
const idx = array.findIndex(num => num === findNum)
console.log(array.slice(idx))
```